# How to vertically strech child of stretched flex child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a column flexbox container. I can stretch one of the flexbox child, but I can find how to stretch its children. See example (`.flex-child-2-child` and `.flex-child-2-child-child` should stretch vertically to fill `.flex-child-2`) :

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 4px solid green;
}

.flex-child-1 {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: SteelBlue;
}

.flex-child-2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: LightSeaGreen;
}

.flex-child-2-child-child,
.flex-child-2-child {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-child-2-child-child {
  background-color: Tomato;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-child-2-child-child > div {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
}
.flex-child-2-child-child > div + div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-child flex-child-1">
  Test
</div>
<div class="flex-child flex-child-2">
  <div class="flex-child-2-child">
    <div class="flex-child-2-child-child">
      <div>Hello</div>
      <div>Word!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I could use `height` instead of `min-height`on `body`, but then long content would overflow out of `body`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.flex-child-1 {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: SteelBlue;
}

.flex-child-2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: LightSeaGreen;
}

.flex-child-2-child-child,
.flex-child-2-child {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-child-2-child-child {
  background-color: Tomato;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child-2-child-child>div {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 100px;
}

.flex-child-2-child-child>div+div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-child flex-child-1">
  Test
</div>
<div class="flex-child flex-child-2">
  <div class="flex-child-2-child">
    <div class="flex-child-2-child-child">
      <div>Hello</div>
      <div>Word!
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to `.flex-child-2`

And

`display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex: 1;` to `.flex-child-2-child-child, .flex-child-2-child` to stretch the elements

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-child-1 {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: SteelBlue;
}

.flex-child-2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: LightSeaGreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-child-2-child-child,
.flex-child-2-child {
  /* height: 100%; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-child-2-child-child {
  background-color: Tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-child flex-child-1">
  Test
</div>
<div class="flex-child flex-child-2">
  <div class="flex-child-2-child">
    <div class="flex-child-2-child-child">
      Hello Word!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue I have is that in the final project, one of the children already has `display:flex; flex-direction: row`, I am editing my question to reflect it.

Comment: Please update the questions with real issue scenario so that this can be checked.

Comment: It's done I edited it

Comment: All right, the "flexbox row child" should only get an additional `flex: 1` and it works.

Comment: Please approve the ansr if tis works for you.